# How to move struct variable with Mutex data in Rust?

Tags: rust, mutex

I'm trying to translate a C++ program that uses a Bank object, with methods that change an account's balance and uses mutexes so this can happen in parallel. In this program, each account had a lock I needed to access before I can modify the data. In C++, the Bank object is global, with many locks to protect the data. In Rust, I created a Struct Bank, where I attempted to use Arc<Mutex<i32>> and Mutex<i32>, to have an issue with moving the data to the thread, because it doesn't implement Copy. I'm fully aware I can just put Arc<Mutex<Bank>>, but in order to make it more similar to the C++ code, I want to try to just protect specific data. Here's some code: 
Bank.rs

```
use std::sync::{ Arc, Mutex };

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Account {
    account_id: i32,
    balance: Arc<Mutex<i64>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Bank {
    num: Arc<Mutex<i32>>,
    num_succ: Arc<Mutex<i32>>,
    num_fail: Arc<Mutex<i32>>,
    accounts: Vec<Account>,
}

pub fn init(n: i32) -> Bank {
    let mut accounts: Vec<Account> = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..n {
        accounts.push(Account {
            account_id: i,
            balance: Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)),
        });
    }
    Bank {
        num: Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)),
        num_succ: Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)),
        num_fail: Arc::new(Mutex::new(0)),
        accounts: accounts,
    }
}

impl Bank {
    pub fn print_account(&self) {
        for i in &self.accounts {
            let balance_lock = i.balance.lock().unwrap();
            println!("ID# {} | {}", i.account_id, balance_lock);
        }

        println!(
            "Success: {} Fails: {}", 
            self.num_succ.lock().unwrap(), 
            self.num_fail.lock().unwrap(),
        );
    }
    pub fn record_succ(&self, message: String) {
        let mut succ_lock = self.num_succ.lock().unwrap();
        println!("{message}");
        *succ_lock+=1;
    }
    pub fn record_fail(&self, message: &str) {
        let mut fail_lock = self.num_fail.lock().unwrap();
        println!("{message}");
        *fail_lock+=1;
    }
    pub fn deposit(&self, worker_id: i32, ledger_id: i32, account_id: i32, amount: i32) {
        let account = self.accounts.get(account_id as usize).unwrap();
        let mut balance_lock = account.balance.lock().unwrap();
        *balance_lock += amount as i64;
        self.record_succ(format!("Worker {worker_id} completed ledger {ledger_id}: deposit {} into account {account_id}", *balance_lock));
    }
}
```

main.rs

```
use std::{
    process,
    thread,
    env,
};
use crate::bank::*;

pub mod bank;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() < 3 {
        eprintln!("Usage: {} <num_of_threads>\n", args[0]);
        process::exit(1);
    }
    let num = args[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(-1);
    
    let bank = bank::init(10);
    let mut workers = Vec::new();

    for id in 0..num {
        // ERROR on move: move occurs because `bank` has type `bank::Bank`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
        let worker = thread::spawn(move || worker(id, &bank));
        workers.push(worker);
    }
    for worker in workers {
        worker.join().unwrap();
    }
}

fn worker(worker_id: i32, bank: &Bank) {
    let mut size = i32::MAX;
    bank.deposit(worker_id, 0, 1, 800);
}
```

The goal is to lock specific account balances and modify in  parallel. I have several methods for the Bank Struct that will do these operations on self.

Comment: It's not clear how `worker(id, l, &bank)` would fail due to `&bank` not being `Copy` — `bank` is behind a reference, and references are `Copy`, so it shouldn't matter. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: Sometimes with Rust your life is a lot easier with a message-passing method between threads than it is to try and lock things across many threads.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As irrelevant notes, using atomics is almost always better than `Mutex<primitive>` and using different mutexes for different fields may be a great mistake, if you need to update some fields together this could be a source of synchronization problems.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I edited the post to make a Minimal Reproducible Example. The 'move' is the issue, because it says Bank doesn't implement Copy, but when I derive Copy, it says the Arc<Mutex>> doesn't implement Copy (in the struct)

Comment: I may have solved my issue. By using std::sync::OnceLock, I was able to make BANK global static variable, and initialize it in main(), while being able to use it in the threads without any current issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Arc<Mutex>` for each field, use just `Mutex`, and wrap the whole `Bank` in `Arc`. Then you can clone it:

```rust
use crate::bank::*;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::{env, process, thread};

pub mod bank {
    use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Account {
        account_id: i32,
        balance: Mutex<i64>,
    }

    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct Bank {
        num: Mutex<i32>,
        num_succ: Mutex<i32>,
        num_fail: Mutex<i32>,
        accounts: Vec<Account>,
    }

    pub fn init(n: i32) -> Arc<Bank> {
        let mut accounts: Vec<Account> = Vec::new();
        for i in 0..n {
            accounts.push(Account {
                account_id: i,
                balance: Mutex::new(0),
            });
        }
        Arc::new(Bank {
            num: Mutex::new(0),
            num_succ: Mutex::new(0),
            num_fail: Mutex::new(0),
            accounts: accounts,
        })
    }

    impl Bank {
        pub fn print_account(&self) {
            for i in &self.accounts {
                let balance_lock = i.balance.lock().unwrap();
                println!("ID# {} | {}", i.account_id, balance_lock);
            }

            println!(
                "Success: {} Fails: {}",
                self.num_succ.lock().unwrap(),
                self.num_fail.lock().unwrap(),
            );
        }
        pub fn record_succ(&self, message: String) {
            let mut succ_lock = self.num_succ.lock().unwrap();
            println!("{message}");
            *succ_lock += 1;
        }
        pub fn record_fail(&self, message: &str) {
            let mut fail_lock = self.num_fail.lock().unwrap();
            println!("{message}");
            *fail_lock += 1;
        }
        pub fn deposit(&self, worker_id: i32, ledger_id: i32, account_id: i32, amount: i32) {
            let account = self.accounts.get(account_id as usize).unwrap();
            let mut balance_lock = account.balance.lock().unwrap();
            *balance_lock += amount as i64;
            self.record_succ(format!("Worker {worker_id} completed ledger {ledger_id}: deposit {} into account {account_id}", *balance_lock));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() < 3 {
        eprintln!("Usage: {} <num_of_threads>\n", args[0]);
        process::exit(1);
    }
    let num = args[1].parse::<i32>().unwrap_or(-1);

    let bank = bank::init(10);
    let mut workers = Vec::new();

    for id in 0..num {
        // ERROR on move: move occurs because `bank` has type `bank::Bank`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
        let worker = thread::spawn({
            let bank = Arc::clone(&bank);
            move || worker(id, &bank)
        });
        workers.push(worker);
    }
    for worker in workers {
        worker.join().unwrap();
    }
}

fn worker(worker_id: i32, bank: &Bank) {
    let mut size = i32::MAX;
    bank.deposit(worker_id, 0, 1, 800);
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's pretty cool. Does this allow for the Bank's content to be updated in parallel? Such as having 2 threads doing a deposit, and as long as its not the same account, it runs both at the same time?

Comment: @Naginipython Yes. As long as they don't try to access the same `Mutex`, they're not blocked on each other.